# glBeginQuery GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using glQuery for getting info about FPS count in my application:

```
CollectDataBegin();

/*all drawing operations with OpenGL*/

CollectDataEnd();
```

Where:

```
void RenderingInfo::CollectDataBegin()
{
    //FPS begin
    available = 0;
    GLenum eError;
// UPDATE 1 START
        if (!bQueryGenerated){ 
            glGenQueries(1, queries); 
            bQueryGenerated = true;
        }
// UPDATE 1 END
    //GL_NO_ERROR from glGetError();
    glBeginQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED, queries[0]);
    //GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error from glGetError();
    //FPS end
}

void RenderingInfo::CollectDataEnd()
    {
        //FPS begin
        glEndQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED);

        iFramesCount++;

        if (iFramesCount == 20)
        {
            iFramesCount = 0;

            while (!available) {
                glGetQueryObjectiv(queries[0], GL_QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE, &available);
            }

            glGetQueryObjectui64v(queries[0], GL_QUERY_RESULT, &timeElapsed);

            float jeb = static_cast<float>(timeElapsed) / std::pow(10, 9);

            xRenderStats.fFPS = static_cast<float>(1.0 / jeb);

                sFPS = std::to_string(xRenderStats.fFPS);
// UPDATE 1 START
                if (bQueryGenerated){
                    glDeleteQueries(1, queries);
                    bQueryGenerated = false;
                }
// UPDATE 1 END
        }
}
```

Private members of `RenderingInfo` class:

```
GLuint queries[] = {0};
GLint available = 0;
GLuint64 timeElapsed;
int iFramesCount = 0;
bool bQueryGenerated = false; //UPADTE 1
```

I wrote and tested this code using Nvidia GeForce GTX760 with newest drivers and I had no problems at all.
But after switching to my integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600 I'm recieving `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` after calling `glBeginQuery()`. Interesting thing is that I'm not getting this error right away but after making some calls to `glBeginQuery()`.

I wasn't been able to find any posts related to this matter so I'm asking for Your help is solving this issue.

UPDATE 1:
I modified my code accoring to @Ike advices, but I'm still recieving an `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error.

Comment: Do you make calls to `glDeleteQueries`? I see `glGenQueries` but no corresponding delete, though that shouldn't cause this prob since it looks like you only use one query object the entire time. Another thing to potentially check -- ensuring valid display context (and matching one).

Comment: Another thing to try -- it seems like you are assuming that a query ID of `0` is an invalid value that will never be returned by `glGenQueries`. I haven't encountered anything in the docs (unless I overlooked something) that suggests that glGenQueries can't output an ID of 0. So I would check if you are indeed only calling glGenQueries once and not overwriting a valid query object with an ID of 0.

Comment: @Ike: I'm making a call to `glDeleteQueries()` in the class destructor, because I'm generating only one query in the class lifetime. Should I delete and recreate query after `glGetQueryObjectui64v()` ? What do you mean by "ensuring  valid display context"? Before performing any rendering operations I'm checking `if (wglGetCurrentContext() != m_hrc)` and statement is true I'm calling: `wglMakeCurrent(m_hdc, m_hrc);`

Comment: Given the way you are using it and immediately outside of your rendering code, it's probably unlikely to be related to display context.  One thing I'd check out is that assumption that "0 means invalid" here: `if (queries[0] == 0)` -- zero might not be a suitable magic number here to assume an invalid query ID that needs to be allocated. That code there might actually attempt to overwrite a valid one.

Comment: @Ike: "I would check if you are indeed only calling glGenQueries once and not overwriting a valid query object with an ID of 0." You are right I will modify my code

Comment: If that doesn't work out, it might be worth trying to add calls to `glDeleteQueries` (just as something to try) in your `CollectDataEnd` method. It's just a sanity check kind of thing to try to get to the root of the problem, or even try to find out if it's the somewhat rare but not impossible driver-side glitch. The display context issue might also show up in trying to call `glDeleteQueries` in your destructor -- I don't know when you actually destroy this object, but sometimes it can be pesky to ensure that a display context is valid when trying to free C++ resources through a dtor...

Comment: ... when wrapping GL code into object-oriented code, and trying to make gl calls when a context isn't valid can lead to all kinds of bizarre issues/side effects.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the code associated with `glQuery` my app no longer produces `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` errors. Since I was using this funcionality for counting time in which single frame is rendered, I replaced it with more reliable method:

```
void RenderingInfo::CollectDataBegin()
{
    //FPS begin
    ctTimeBegin = clock();
    //FPS end
}

void RenderingInfo::CollectDataEnd()
    {
    //FPS begin
    ctTimeEnd = clock();

    dElapsedTime += (static_cast<double>((ctTimeEnd - ctTimeBegin))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    iFramesCount++;

    if (iFramesCount == 20)
    {
        if ((dElapsedTime / iFramesCount) < (1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)){
            xRenderStats.fFPS = 60.0f;
        }
        else{
            xRenderStats.fFPS = static_cast<float>(iFramesCount / dElapsedTime);
        }

        sFPS = std::to_string(xRenderStats.fFPS);

        dElapsedTime = 0.0;
        iFramesCount = 0;
    }
    //FPS end
}
```

Private `RenderingInfo` members:

```
int iFramesCount =0;
clock_t ctTimeBegin = 0;
clock_t ctTimeEnd = 0;
double dElapsedTime = 0.0;
```

**This is not the answer** for a question why I received `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`, but it's for showing a possible way out when someone will end up with the similar problem.

Comment: It may work for you, but you should be aware that you're measuring something entirely different now. You original code was measuring GPU time. Your new code is measuring CPU time. These two are mostly unrelated.

Comment: Well, you are right in both cases. Now I measuring CPU time and this will work for me because I call CollectDataBegin() at the beginnig of the rendering pipeline and CollectDataEnd() after SwapBuffers() call (which is very important and I didn't mentioned this and I'm sorry about that)